# Sqlite select duplicate values from two columns

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, duplicates

I have a work for school and I have this table (not complete I simplified it):

```
email           region      card         quantidade
--------------  ----------  -----------  ----------
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Flamestrike  2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Fireball     2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Polymorph    3
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Water Eleme  6
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Arcane Expl  3
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Frostbolt    2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Arcane Miss  8
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Mirror Imag  2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Archamage A  1
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Pyroblast    2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  US          Pyroblast    1
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Kirin Tor M  3
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Goblin Blas  2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Unstable Po  11
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Iron sensei  2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Shady Deale  2
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Backstab     5
dummyEmail_1@box.net  EU          Deadly Pois  3
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Deathwing    2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Nefarian     2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Volcanic Dr  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Twilight Dr  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Cenarius     2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          King Krush   2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Archmage An  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Tirion Ford  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Prophet Vel  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Edward VanC  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Al'Akir the  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Lord Jaraxx  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Grommash He  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Dr.Boom      2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Mimiron's H  2
protoEmail_2@box.net  EU          Bolvar Ford  2
```

And want to output this from a query:

```
email           card                 region
--------------  -------------------  ----------
protoEmail_2@box.net  Grommash Hellscream  EU
protoEmail_2@box.net  Grommash Hellscream  US
protoEmail_2@box.net  Lord Jaraxxus        EU
protoEmail_2@box.net  Lord Jaraxxus        AS
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Mind Control         EU
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Mind Control         US
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Pyroblast            EU
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Pyroblast            US
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Shady Dealer         EU
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Shady Dealer         US
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Unstable Portal      EU
dummyEmail_2@box.net  Unstable Portal      US
protoEmail_2@box.net  Varian Wrynn         EU
protoEmail_2@box.net  Varian Wrynn         US
```

i.e: I want to select all the duplicates from email and card and show the region of the duplicate card/email

I tried this query but it gives me a syntax error: `SELECT email, card, region FROM player_card WHERE (email,card) IN (SELECT email,card FROM player_card GROUP BY email,card HAVING count(*) > 1) ORDER BY card;`

Table creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE player_card
(email VARCHAR(30),
region VARCHAR(2) CHECK (region IN("US", "EU", "AS")),
card VARCHAR(30),
quantidade INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(email, region, card),
FOREIGN KEY(email) REFERENCES player(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(region) REFERENCES player(region),
FOREIGN KEY(card) REFERENCES card(name)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get the result by using join instead of the in operator:

```
SELECT p.email, p.card, p.region FROM player_card p join 
(SELECT email,card, count(*) as cnt FROM player_card GROUP BY email,card) t 
on p.email = t.email and p.card=t.card where t.cnt>1 
ORDER BY p.card;
```

[live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9dd08/1/0)